# Basics for starting an open source node project's contribution guidelines

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, open-source, jslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm planning to start an open source project

currently in the planning stage

I've finalized the tech stack and it'll be mostly node in the back-end and JS SPA framework in the front-end

Currently, I'm documenting contribution guidelines.

I want the project to be strictly unit tested and the code should adhere to  [Airbnb JS style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript)

which methodologies should I implement to force every contributor to comply
with the requirements

links to Any similar project or any tools/library would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on the technical possibilities here, so an answer that focuses on the *soft* aspects in here: first of all, look into your own attitude. If you really think you want to **force** something on people that you ask to work with you on a project, you are (to a certain degree) already going down the wrong rabbit hole.

My suggestion: focus on clearly describing and documenting your expectations. Make it clear for any future participants what kind of input should be provided. And be ready to **lead by example**. Make sure that *anything* that you add to the project is absolutely, to 100% meeting these goals for quality, form, content that you put up initially. And from there on: be ready to review other people's input. "lint" like tooling might be able to catch rule violations - but even nicely formatted code can be "not clean", not readable, not maintainable.

Thus be ready to spent significant amounts of time doing code reviews - trying to give encourage positive behaviour and give helpful, constructive suggestions for input that isn't up to your standards.

Comment: maybe in question, I came out bit arrogant or rude but all I want is to adhere to a standard codebase 

off course code reviewing is the defacto requirement for the fulfillment of the project and yes that should be my primary responsibility.

 I just want the codebase to not become a spaghetti causing weird inconsistencies all around

Comment: Sure. My main point is to create *awareness*. Even one wrong word here or there can create impressions on the receiving side of your communication that you did not intend to create. As you just noticed ;-)